# Is there a way in csh to dynamically check environment variables?

Tags: csh

I have a c application that calls out to a csh script with lots of information. I'd like to expand that in such a way that the csh script can loop through the environment variables. For example, the c application would set the following envs

```
COUNT=4
SOMETHING_1=HELLO
SOMETHING_2=WORLD
SOMETHING_3=WIDE
SOMETHING_4=WEB
```

And the csh script can loop through the SOMETHINGs and print out the envs based on the count env.

Is it possible to evaluate a programatically generated env?

I tried doing this to test the theory:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

foreach n ( 1 2 3 4 )
        eval "$SOMETHING"_"$n"
end
```

But that obviously didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you're missing is a `\` char, i.e.

```
#!/bin/csh -f

foreach n ( 1 2 3 4 )
        eval echo \$"SOMETHING"_"$n"
        # --------^--- here
end
```

I've added an `echo` here so that `eval` has something safe, but visible to do.

Change your shebang line to use debug/trace mode, i.e.

```
#!/bin/csh -fvx
```

and define

```
     SOMETHING=abc
```

and you'll see the two passes that the `eval` does, you'll (should) see
where

```
 echo $SOMETHING_1
 echo "value of abc_1 =$abc_1 XXX"
```

but of course, you'll have to define a value for variable abc_1.

Finally, don't get to rely on using eval. Use it only as a last resort, and only where you have control over what strings will be `eval`ed.

It would be very easy for a malcontent to pass in harmful code that will be executed by the `eval`.

(And sorry, I don't have a `csh` handy to test this so let me know if you have troubles).

Finally, read widely published articles that `csh` is not a great language for programming. Switch to `bash` or `ksh` at your earliest convenience. You won't regret it.

IHTH

Comment: I tried your approach and am getting the env variable names as output:

a_1
a_2
a_3
a_4

using this code:

#!/bin/csh -f
set SO=a

foreach n ( 1 2 3 4 )
        eval echo "\$SO"_"$n"
end

NOTE: I shortened my environment variables to a_1 a_2 a_3 and a_4.

Comment: Woot! you were close! 

eval echo \$"$SO"_"$n"

is the correct string. I'll update your answer and give you cred!

Comment: Further: yeah I know about how terrible csh is; this is one of those usual sob stories about how I can't do anything to change our reliance on it :(

Comment: The problem with this is that evaluating an undefined variable is an error.

Comment: I read the question too quickly and thought that the problem required determining whether the variables are set or unset. If you can assume that they're all set, then your approach is ok -- but it's probably not a bad idea to check, since an error will terminate the script.

Comment: @darrickc : I didn't approve your edit because I was skeptical. I fired up a `csh`, and I'm really surprized, it has to be `eval echo \$"SOMETHING_$n"` (with the `\$` outside of the dbl-quotes). Dang, I don't recall that! Thanks for the correction, I've fixed my answer. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 3):

If one of the variables is not set, your script will crash; referring to an undefined variable in csh/tcsh is an error. (This is unlike sh/bash, where `$FOO` by default expands to the empty string if the variable isn't set.)

If you can safely assume that all the relevant variables are set, then shellter's solution should be ok. If you want to do some error checking, read on.

The csh/tcsh syntax for testing whether a variable `$VAR` is defined or not is `$?VAR`. It evaluates to `0` or `1`.

An example:

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

setenv SOMETHING_1 foo
setenv SOMETHING_3 bar

foreach i (1 2 3 4 5)
    set is_set = `eval echo '$?SOMETHING_'$i`
    if ($is_set) then
        echo '$SOMETHING_'$i is set to `eval echo '$SOMETHING_'$i`
    else
        echo '$SOMETHING_'$i is not set
    endif
end
```

Output:

```
$SOMETHING_1 is set to foo
$SOMETHING_2 is not set
$SOMETHING_3 is set to bar
$SOMETHING_4 is not set
$SOMETHING_5 is not set
```

As shellter's answer mentions, `eval` is potentially unsafe unless you have complete control over what's passed to it. In this particular case that's not an issue.

Another possible solution might be to parse the output of `printenv` -- but that could run into problems if some environment variables have values with strange characters such as newlines.

Or you could write and invoke a small program in another language; for example C's `getenv()` or Perl's `%ENV` don't require the use of `eval` to determine whether an arbitrary environment variable is set or not, and are not vulnerable to values with strange characters.

I vaguely recall that in some old versions of csh, the `$?VAR` syntax worked only for shell variables, not for environment variables. It does work in tcsh and in more modern versions of csh.

Comment: As always, good stuff. (the `$?var` syntax worked on Sun3, but that's as far back as I go ;-) ). Good luck to all.